# Can't click submit button CakePHP + Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a code here and my problem is I can't click the submit button. I don't know if it is because of Bootstrap or anything. And I feel that the select options might be the reasons.Here's my code. Please help! I'm using CakePHP 1.3 and Bootstrap 3.0

```
<?php
$this->layout = 'admin_layout';
$ewan = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
$currtime = date('m/d/Y');

echo $this->Form->create('Event', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
?>

<?php
echo $this->Form->hidden('Event.date_published', array('value' => $currtime));
echo $this->Form->hidden('Event.user_id', array('value' => $ewan));
?>                                        
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Event Topic</label>
    <div class="col-md-11"> 
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Event.topic', array('options' => array("Auto, Boat & Air" => "Auto, Boat & Air", "Business & Professional" => "Business & Professional", "Charity & Causes" => "Charity & Causes", "Community & Culture" => "Community & Culture", "Family & Education" => "Family & Education", "Fashion & Beauty" => "Fashion & Beauty", "Film, Media & Entertainment" => "Film, Media & Entertainment", "Food & Drink" => "Food & Drink", "Government & Politics" => "Government & Politics", "Health & Wellness" => "Health & Wellness", "Hobbies & Special Interest" => "Hobbies & Special Interest", "Home & Lifestyle" => "Home & Lifestyle", "Music" => "Music", "Other" => "Other", "Performing & Visual Arts" => "Performing & Visual Arts", "Religion & Spirituality" => "Religion & Spirituality", "Science & Technology" => "Science & Technology", "Seasonal & Holiday" => "Seasonal & Holiday", "Sports & Fitness" => "Sports & Fitness", "Travel & Outdoor" => "Travel & Outdoor"), 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control select', 'empty' => 'Select event topic', 'required' => 'required')); ?><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Event Type</label>
    <div class="col-md-11"> 
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Event.type', array('options' => array("Appearance or Signing" => "Appearance or Signing", "Attraction" => "Attraction", "Camp, Trip, or Retreat" => "Camp, Trip, or Retreat", "Class, Training, or Workshop" => "Class, Training, or Workshop", "Concert or Performance" => "Concert or Performance", "Conference" => "Conference", "Convention" => "Convention", "Dinner or Gala" => "Dinner or Gala", "Festival or Fair" => "Festival or Fair", "Game or Competition" => "Game or Competition", "Meeting or Networking Event" => "Meeting or Networking Event", "Other" => "Other", "Party or Social Gathering" => "Party or Social Gathering", "Race or Endurance Event" => "Race or Endurance Event", "Rally" => "Rally", "Screening" => "Screening", "Seminar or Talk" => "Seminar or Talk", "Tour" => "Tour", "Tournament" => "Tournament", "Tradeshow, Consumer Show, or Expo" => "Tradeshow, Consumer Show, or Expo"), 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control select', 'required' => 'required', 'empty' => 'Select type of event')); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>                       
</div>

<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->submit('Publish Event', array('class' => 'btn btn-info btn-lg'));
            echo $this->Form->end();
            ?> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <?php
            echo $this->Html->link(
                    'Cancel', array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'index'), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg')
            );
            ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there, Could you please print the view page source? Right click on the form and go inspect element, (Chrome), sometimes there might be overlapping forms or something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output code is not good structured.

Move `echo $this->Form->end();`  after last closing div tag `</div>`